# Combining two negated file check conditions (-f and -s) seems to return incorrect result

Tags: linux, bash

I want to check if a file is a file and exists and if it is not empty, so ended up using a combined check with `-f` and `-s`. I want to return up front if the file does not exist or is empty so I am negating both checks.

To test the scenario where my file name returned empty string and I am passing a path to a directory I am trying this:

```
if [[ ! -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] && [[ ! -s "/path/to/dir/" ]]; 
then  echo "Does not exists"; else echo "Exists"; fi
```

> Exists

Above returns 'Exist' which seems incorrect.

`-f` check alone is correct:

```
if [[ ! -f "/path/to/dir/" ]]; then  echo "Does not exists"; 
else echo "Exists"; fi
```

> Does not exists

The combined check but without negating each is correct as well:

```
if [[ -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] && [[ -s "/path/to/dir/" ]]; 
then  echo "Exists"; else echo "Does not exists"; fi
```

> Does not exists

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if there is some strangeness in Bash when combining negated conditions with logical and `&&`?

Edit 1:
As suggested tried with notation where both conditions are in the same set of brackets:

```
if [[ ! -f "/opt/gmdemea/smartmap_V2/maps/" && ! -s "/opt/gmdemea/smartmap_V2/maps/" ]]; then  echo "Does not exists"; else echo "Exists"; fi
```

> Exists

But that does not change the behavior.

Edit 2:
From man page it seems that in this situation `-s` should be enough but when passed existing directory path it returns true (Bash version: 4.1.2(1)-release):

```
if [[ -s "/opt/gmdemea/smartmap_V2/maps/" ]]; then echo "Exists"; else echo "Does not exists"; fi
```

> Exists

It returns 'Exists' while it is not a file so should be going to else clause returning 'Does not exists'

Comment: Please read about [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: For the directory, you should probably use `if [[ ! -d "/path/to/dir/" ]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `x AND y`, then nagating it you get: `NOT (x AND y)`. This is equal to `(NOT a) OR (NOT b)`. It is **not** equal to `(NOT x) AND (NOT y)`.

> I want to check if a file is a file and exists and if it is not empty

If you want to check if a file is a regular file and if it is not empty, then you do:

```
[[ -f path ]] && [[ -s path ]]
```

The negation would be (each line is equal) (note [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
! ( [[ -f path ]] && [[ -s path ]] )
[[ ! -f path || ! -s path ]]
```

Which you can write also as (each line is equal):

```
! [[ -f path && -s path ]]
[[ ! ( -f path && -s path ) ]]
[[ ! -f path ]] || [[ ! -s path ]]
# or using `[` test and `-a` and `-o`:
! [ -f path -a -s path ]
[ ! -f path -o ! -s path ]
[ ! \( -f path -a -s path \) ]
```

So just:

```
if [[ ! -f "/path/to/dir/" || ! -s "/path/to/dir/" ]]; then
     echo "The /path/to/dir is not a regular file or size is nonzero"
else
     echo "The path /path/to/dir is a regular file and it's size is zero"
fi
```

Comment: I'm side-eyeing the slash on the end of `/path/to/dir/` and thinking it's worth comment, but having a hard time articulating this morning. Maybe add a note at the bottom as an aside to clarify that if the slash is there, it *is* a directory?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk mybe you are using different Bash version (I am on 4.1.2(1)-release) and -s is not enough. If I pass existing directory path like this: `if [[ -s "/opt/gmdemea/smartmap_V2/maps/" ]]; then  echo "Exists"; else echo "Does not exists"; fi` it returns 'Exists' while it is not a file so should be going to else clause and return 'Does not exist'.

Comment: @PiotrPanczyk you are right. I think it's treating dir as a file with zero size... : /

Comment: @KamilCuk I think you misread my first example: `if [[ ! -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] && [[ ! -s "/path/to/dir" ]]; then  echo "Does not exists"; else echo "Exists"; fi`  In This case both conditions return true as you explained and it should return 'Does not exists' but instead it is goinf to else clause and returns 'Exists'

Comment: @EdMorton I think because theoretically `[[ a ]] || [[ b ]]` will run two processes while `[[ a || b ]]` will run only one. Note that the `b` is not processed if `a` is false in both cases. Less processes usually result in faster scripts. And it's less to type. I admit, I didn't give that statement enough thought (but I think I stand by it anyway and will still use `&&` `||` inside `[[` in my scripts)

Comment: @KamilCuk I understood '-s' same as you and used in alone in the code and it  got me into troubles. That's why started to investigate this.

Comment: As for the `[[ ! -f "/path/to/dir/" || ! -s "/path/to/dir/" ]]` this answer is correct, indeed the `test -s /dir` returns true if /dir exists and false if dir does not exist.

Comment: @KamilCuk It is technically correct but as stated in question: I want to check if a file is a regular file and exists and if it is not empty. Now I could have just do it without negating: `if [[ -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] && [[ -s "/path/to/dir/" ]]; 
then  echo "Exists"; else echo "Does not exists"; fi` which is working fine but I would have to do more changes in the code, getting all the statement in the true clause and copy into else clause, while technically the condition with negations should work. So the point is why this is not working in Bash.

Comment: @PiotrPanczyk you understand that the negation of `a && b` is **not** `!a && !b`, right? It's `!(a && b)` which is `!a || !b`.

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right `[[ ! -f "/path/to/dir/" || ! -s "/path/to/dir/" ]]` is correct answer . You and @EdMorton are correct. Marking @KamilCuk answer as correct since he was first and up voting both.

Comment: @EdMorton yes I got it now, got myself confused there.

Answer (score 4):

@KamilCuk already explained the logic flaw but in general - always avoid using negatives in your code, e.g. `!` in this case, as they make the code harder to read (and get right) than using positives. Instead of:

```
if [[ ! -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] && [[ ! -s "/path/to/dir" ]]
then
    echo "Does not exists"
else
    echo "Exists"
fi
```

if you applied boolean algebra to factor out the `!`s then you'd get:

```
if ! ( [[ -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] || [[ -s "/path/to/dir" ]] )
then
    echo "Does not exists"
else
    echo "Exists"
fi
```

which you can then flip the if/else in to get rid of the final `!`:

```
if [[ -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] || [[ -s "/path/to/dir" ]]
then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exists"
fi
```

which you can immediately see at a glance is not the the test you were trying for. Instead you'd want:

```
if [[ -f "/path/to/dir/" ]] && [[ -s "/path/to/dir" ]]
then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exists"
fi
```

Comment: @EdMorton It's good suggestion and I understand that it is not the best practice but wanted to avoid flipping if/else and mentioned in the original question that the version of this condition without negations works fine. Checked factoring out the `!` it does not help still returns incorrect. All three versions of this conditions are logically equivalent and the point is why it is not working in Bash is there a bug?

Comment: No, there is not a bug. You're doing something wrong in your code. Best i can tell from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870982/bash-combining-two-negated-file-check-conditions-f-and-s-seems-to-return-i/56872046?noredirect=1#comment100293215_56871431) you're still using `!a && !b` instead of `!a || !b`.

Comment: @EdMorton Maybe I am missing something aside of the condition not following best practices and being not as readable as flipping if/else and not using '!' I do not see an issue from logic point of view?

Comment: @EdMorton Your correct using `!a || !b` is correct, managed to confuse myself well enough here.